# Does any complete and transitive strict preference relation let us order a finite set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand that it is a very simple question, but somehow I can't get how to provide a clear proof of whether this statement is true or false.

It is obvious that if we have two candidates $x,y \in X$ for the same number, we can order them because of the completeness of the relation. Also cycles like $x>z, z>x$ are impossible due to transitivity (Let "$>$" be the notation for the relation). What else can happen? Why the set should be finite but not countable?

EDIT: I suppose that there can be a mistake in the task that I'm solving at the moment and the relation should be not strict. But why it can be not true for arbitrary complete and transitive preference relation?

Comment: Any set can be ordered,

Comment: @GitGud: But not necessarily by a given preference relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is finite, and $>$ is a complete, transitive, strict preference relation on $X$. For each $x\in X$ let $p(x)=|\{y\in X:x>y\}|$, the number of elements to which $x$ is preferred. If $x,y\in X$, and $x>y$, then clearly $p(x)>p(y)$. Suppose that $x,y\in X$, and $p(x)=p(y)$; we’ve just shown that this is impossible if $x>y$ or $y>x$, so $x=y$. Thus, the map $x\mapsto p(x)$ is injective and order-preserving (using the usual ordering of the natural numbers). This shows that $>$ linearly orders $X$. (In fact you can show by induction that the range of $p$ is $\{0,1,\ldots,|X|-1\}$.)

However, it’s true in general that if $>$ is a complete, transitive, strict preference relation on $X$, then the relation $\ge$ defined by $x\ge y$ iff $x>y$ or $x=y$ is a linear (= total) order on $X$. This order need not have various other nice properties, however: it need not be a well-order, it need not be Dedekind complete, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't thought of such a construction with $p(x)$, now I see how it works.

Comment: @hcl14: You’re welcome!